# "No data" after sending tx Jupiter Swap Python

Tags: python, transactions, solana

I have a python script that is connected to the Jupiter API and I am trying to ensure the transaction goes through. However I've been having a lot of trouble trying to figure out why sometimes it goes through with no Issue and other times it gives me a tx hash back but the tx hash just shows No data on solscan/explorer

```
swap_instruction = response_data["swapTransaction"]
raw_tx = VersionedTransaction.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(swap_instruction))
signature = keypair.sign_message(solders.message.to_bytes_versioned(raw_tx.message))
signed_tx = VersionedTransaction.populate(raw_tx.message, [signature])
encoded_tx = base64.b64encode(bytes(signed_tx)).decode('utf-8')

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}
data = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "sendTransaction",
    "params": [
        encoded_tx,
        {
            "skipPreflight": True,
            "preflightCommitment": "finalized",
            "encoding": "base64"
        }
    ]
}
tx_response = requests.post(rpc_url, headers=headers, json=data)
```

The swapTransaction comes directly from the Juputer quote API and that is all being pushed into the payload.

I've tried adding prioritizationFeeLamports up to 1000000 I've also done the same and tried computeUnitPriceMicroLamports instead of the prioritizationFeeLamports but still some txs just go through and some appear to go through but have no data on solscan. I've also never had a tx actually physically fail, just either success or a no show.

Comment: This is normal -- due to high congestion on the network right now, even with high priority fees, it's possible that your transaction never arrives at the leader due to connection throttling. You can try resending your transaction (without resigning) until the blockhash expires.